# Getting Table is in readonly mode error when trying to drop a partition on Clickhouse Replicated Table

Tags: database, clickhouse, partition

ALTER TABLE dbName.rTable  DROP PARTITION 20220107
I want to run this command on all underlying replicated tables.
when I run this command I get table is in read only mode error.

rTable's are created as:

```
CREATE TABLE dbName.rTable  
(
    `TIME` DateTime('Asia/Istanbul') CODEC(ZSTD(3)),
    `ColumnA` Nullable(Float32) CODEC(ZSTD(3)),
    .
    .
    .

)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/rTable/shard1',
 'rp0')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMMDD(TIME)
ORDER BY (ColumnA,
 TIME)
SETTINGS storage_policy = 'all',
 index_granularity = 8192;
```

My storage policy is as:

```
 <policies>
            <all>
                <volumes>
                    <main>
                        <disk>ssd1</disk>
                        <disk>ssd2</disk>
                        <perform_ttl_move_on_insert>true</perform_ttl_move_on_insert>
                        <prefer_not_to_merge>false</prefer_not_to_merge>
                        <load_balancing>round_robin</load_balancing>
                    </main>
                </volumes>
                <move_factor>0.2</move_factor>
            </all>
        </policies>
```

I have a 4 node system and on each node I have created rTable's and the distributed table over rTable's according to the below config.

```
<ha>
            <shard>
            <internal_replication>false</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                <default_database>dbName</default_database>
                    <host>node1</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                <default_database>dbName</default_database>
                    <host>node2</host>
                    <port>9000</port>

                </replica>
            </shard>
            <shard>
            <internal_replication>false</internal_replication>
                <replica>
                <default_database>dbName</default_database>
                    <host>node3</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
                <replica>
                <default_database>dbName</default_database>
                    <host>node4</host>
                    <port>9000</port>
                </replica>
            </shard>
</ha>
```

PLEASE HELP I need to drop these partitions! Thank in advance

Comment: hi reho - this "table is readonly" error usually means that something not right with the ZooKeeper configuration or syncing. What is your ZooKeeper setup like (or clickhouse-keeper), and are you seeing any errors in metadata replicating there?

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply my Zookeeper Config in Clickhouse config.xml: <zookeeper>
        <node>
                <host>node1</host>
                <port>2181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
                <host>node2</host>
                <port>2181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
                <host>node3</host>
                <port>2181</port>
        </node>
        <node>
                <host>node4</host>
                <port>2181</port>
        </node>
</zookeeper>

Comment: And my Zookeeper zoo.cfg file is like:
tickTime=2000
initLimit=10
syncLimit=5
dataDir=/tmp/zookeeper
clientPort=2181